# UINavigationController doesn't push a view

Tags: ios, ios4, delegates, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have my UINavigationController setup in my app delegate and I used it to push for my log-in page. Once loggeI-in, the view that are being called will show the UITabBarController and has each separate UINavigationController for each tab. My problem is that when I push a view thru navigation controller within my tab bar it does nothing. It doesn't push the view at all. I don't know what to do next to make the pushViewController works. Any help is very much appreciated. Thanks.

Here's my code:

this function will be called when login-- from rootView class

```
- (void) login
{
   UIViewController *_mainPageViewController = [[MainPageViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainPageViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
   [self.navigationController pushViewController:_mainPageViewController animated:YES];
}
```

MainPageViewController.class--

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
   if (self) {  
        [self setUpTabBar];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)setUpTabBar { 

MeViewController *_meViewController = [[MeViewController alloc]init];
_meViewController.tabBarItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"me" 
                                                             image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"img1.png"] tag:1];
UINavigationController *firstNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:_meViewController];

TodoViewController *_todoViewController = [[TodoViewController alloc]init];
_meViewController.tabBarItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"me" 
                                                             image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"img2.png"] tag:1];
UINavigationController *secondNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:_meViewController];

mainBarController.viewControllers = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: firstNavController, secondNavController, nil];
mainBarController.delegate = self;
mainBarController.selectedIndex=0;

[firstNavController release];
[_meViewController release];   
[secondNavController release];
[_exploreViewController release];

[[[UIApplication sharedApplication]keyWindow]addSubview:mainBarController.view];
}
```

MeViewController.class-- it doesn't push the view at all

```
- (IBAction)showMeInfo:(id)sender {
UIViewController *_meInfoViewController = [[MeInfoViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MeInfoViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:_meInfoViewController animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I 100% understand, but here goes -

I assume that `MainPageViewController` is a subclass of `UITabBarController`.  If this is the case, then the `mainBarController` variable is not required, because the tab bar controller in this class will then be `self`. You would call

```
self.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: firstNavController, secondNavController, nil];
```

Also, because you are pushing the instance of `MainPageViewController` onto the existing `UINavigationController` instance, you don't need to do any subview adding inside the `MainPageViewController` code - eg the line of code

```
[[[UIApplication sharedApplication]keyWindow]addSubview:mainBarController.view];
```

is not required, and shouldn't be present (the `UINavigationController` automatically controls which views are visible etc. depending on which view controllers are pushed/popped from the navigation stack.)